# Problem reading ALL Gmail emails via POP3 (Can only ever get first 290!)

Tags: c#, gmail, pop3

For some reason, whenever I'm reading all emails via POP3 Gmail I can only ever receive the first 290 emails! These date back to 2004 and are of little use.

Is there a way to either specify a date range to receive or actually receive them all? I've tried using many different POP3 libraries and got no further, they all receive the same amount of emails.

Although commercial products would be nice, I can't afford them right now so please no suggestions to use the many brilliant commercial POP3 clients.

Thnaks, Daniel.

Comment: Posting the code wouldn't really help as it's different for every POP3 library implementation. It's quite simply, get connected, authenticate, get a count of the emails. Normally just a single command, returning either a long or an int. Always 290.

Comment: What hpppens when you try to access the account with a full POP3 email client?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think google have some problems with pop3 event with outlook , the program downloaded the mails two times .
my work around was  connecting with IMAP  its batter protocol and have more advanced options and google support it , now i try to find good .net IMAP library .
if you managed to get pop3 work with gmail please till us.

Comment: Decided pop was pretty terrible and went with IMAP! Tried to work with about 5 different IMAP libraries and found that they all had pretty huge flaws. Eventually found ImapX (here: http://hellowebapps.com/products/imapx/) and this works really, really well.

Answer (score 4):

For some reason, GMail does this.  I have found that if you apprent the string "recent:" before your user name when sending the USER message, you get more messages, and the most recent (last 30 days).

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing in [the POP3 protocol](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1939) to support retrieving by date, or forcing all messages. The STAT command should tell you how many, and then the LIST command should list them all.

Can you trace the traffic (using Wireshark if necessary) and see what the responses fromn google are? Particularly interesting would be the response to the STAT command:

> [STAT] The positive response consists of
> "+OK" followed by a single space, the
> number of messages in the maildrop, a
> single space, and the size of the
> maildrop in octets.
>
> [LIST] If no argument was given and
> the POP3 server issues a positive
> response, then the response given is
> multi-line. After the initial +OK, for
> each message in the maildrop,  the
> POP3 server responds with a line
> containing information for that
> message.

Comment: I have a similar problem as the original poster; the stat response for me is "+OK 257 1089946" despite there being 336 emails in the account.  This breaks the tool that is attempting to retrieve new messages. It seems something is wrong with the response, but I could be missing something. [LIST] also returns 257. Odd, not sure how to resolve this. Using OpenPOP.Net, would be happy to switch to IMAP if I could find an open source equivalent.